# SQL: How to refer to a dynamic column name to make calculation

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to update fields while referring to a dynamic column.
The goal is to automate a process because each month the column to refer to changes.

For example it's like having different columns like month1, month2, month3 until month24. Each month, only 1 column needs to be updated but it's a running number that is calculated in another table.

So my question is how to make the query dynamic so that every month i only update the column number that i want and not the other one.

I tried the script below but the following issue comes up

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

```
DECLARE @PromoMonthNumber VARCHAR(60)
DECLARE @PromoMonth VARCHAR(600)

SET @PromoMonthNumber = (SELECT CurrentDemandIndex FROM RidgeSys) --This refer to a number that change all the time
SET @PromoMonth = 'SELECT ABC.PromotionHistory' + @PromoMonthNumber


UPDATE ABC
SET @PromoMonth = table2.promotionhistory
FROM ABC
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Article.code as code, sum(ROUND(@PromoMonth,0)) as promotionhistory 
    FROM Article
    INNER JOIN ABC ON DEF.articlecode = ABC.Articlecode
) as table2
ON ABC.articlecode = table2.code)
```

Comment: Can you please un-tag the database which you aren't using.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your issue:

```
SELECT Article.code as code, sum(ROUND(@PromoMonth,0)) as promotionhistory
```

Since `@PromoMonth` is defined as `VARCHAR`, if the value is non-numeric, it will fail.  Here is an example:

This works fine:

```
declare @x varchar(100) = '1';
select sum(round(@x,0));
```

Result:

```
1
```

This fails with same error above:

```
declare @x varchar(100) = 'x';
select sum(round(@x,0));
```

Result:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 3
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

You need to check that the value is numeric before you do the calculation.